# Test class error list has no rows of assignement

Tags: apex, visualforce, unit-test, custom-controller

```
public class identifier {
public String PersonRecord {get;set;}
public account Acc {get;set;}
public list<CommissionerDetails__c> commision{get;set;}   
public PersonConfirmationEnrolment(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{

    PersonRecord =Apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
    Acc=[select id, Ward__c,Salutation__c,GivenName__c,Family_Name__c,LastName,Postal_Address__c,Residential_Address__c,AddressLine1__c,District__c,CouncilArea__c,
         Enrolment_Date__c,Silent_Elector_Flag__c,Person_Status__c,Unable_to_Sign__c from Account where id=: PersonRecord ];    
}
```

---

Test class

```
 Apexpages.StandardController st=new Apexpages.standardController(ad);
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',ad.id);
    PersonConfirmationEnrolment Confirm=new PersonConfirmationEnrolment(st);
```

when trying to call this class in test class, we're getting run time error: 'list has no rows of assignment'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before initialize your controller you need to add Id in the current page parameter

```
PageReference pageRef = Page.YOURVFPAGENAME;
Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);
ApexPages.Standardcontroller st = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(ad);
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id',ad.id);
identifier Confirm=new identifier (st);
```

Comment: done it but getting same error

Comment: @keerthanachowdhary can you add your updated code in question?

Comment: added im ny question can u please check it

Comment: @keerthanachowdhary try with complete code. try to set the currentpage `Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef);` as well

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an [`System.assertEquals(...)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_assertEquals) call before you call the method in your test class to make sure that the data you are about to use has been properly inserted.

```
Id SomeId = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
System.assertEquals(1, [SELECT COUNT() FROM Account WHERE Id = :SomeId]);
```

If your account has been created, and inserted, and a valid Id was returned, then you'll likely need to adjust your page context, via [`Test.setCurrentPage(...)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm#apex_System_Test_setCurrentPage), as described in @Ratan's answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to monkey around with parameters at all. The proper way to get the Id in your extension constructor is:

```
public MyConstructor(ApexPages.StandardController controller)
{
    Id accountId = controller.getId();
}
```

The proper way to set it in your test is just through the controller, no need to set params.

```
ApexPages.StandardController controller = new ApexPages.StandardController(record);
MyExtension extension = new MyExtension(controller);
```

Also note this standard class has a `getRecord` method, so you don't actually need to query. You may need to call `addFields`, though, which has its own problems. None of these approaches will work if your record is not yet inserted.